# video compression using media codec

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I have a video which needs to be compressed in android, Currently m using ffmpeg and it is working fine but i want try with media codec and media muxer. I have already read document in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html and also tried these links:
https://github.com/hoolrory/MediaCodecDemo
and like above many links about media codec.

Can anyone tel me how exactly it works and what are the steps taken??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: rachana, just download zip file and it in your IDE and then run that demo, and give your image path instead of they people's path and check if its working or not. If its working then implement in your code.

Comment: @pratt m talking about video and not image

Comment: yah I know, it was my typing mistake, but you can undestand I think what I mean to say is.

Comment: I have given my own path itself. I just want to know how it exactly works. Because m not understanding the flow. Finally I want a compresses video file

Comment: okay, I need to search over it , and then I will get back to you soon. My office time is over so will know you tomorrow.

Comment: Canonical MediaCodec resources are http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ (info, code snippets) and https://github.com/google/grafika (full app with various demos).

Comment: @fadden I have checked bigflake and now checked grafika. The thing is I'm not understanding how to use it and the concept. So can you explain me how exactly I should work on Video compression. Thank you

Comment: Can you please help how you are using ffmpeg for video compression.